# NetLogo Creating turtles-own as list or array

Tags: arrays, list, netlogo, agent

I do not have experience coding in netlogo, I was wondering if is it possible to make a turtles-own variable as an array or list?

In my case, I tried setting the turtles-own variable to an array but an error comes up "You can't use GO in an observer context, because GO is turtle-only".

I need to store different values as an array or list to one agent, they have the same variable name, changing the name of the variable will not be okay for my code.

```
to test
   file-open "file"
   show "Starting"
   let a1 array:from-list n-values 368[0]
  
   let i 0
   let j 0
   let k 0
  
   while [not file-at-end?][
     let line file-read
     array:set a1 j line
     set  j j + 1
     set i i + 1
     while [i != 7][
     set ETRatioValue array:from-list n-values 8[0]
     ask turtles with [Name = k] [set ETRatioValue array:item a1 k]
     set k k + 1
    ]
     set i  0
     show line
   ]
  
  show "Fishing Ratio"
  show "Adding values to array"
  print a1
  file-close
end
```

Comment: It's definitely possible, but you should post some of your code so people can more easily help you with your issue.

Comment: the error you are getting is not related to arrays or turtles-own variables. what it says is that your GO command is turtle-only, but you haven't posted the code for that...